# How to create a custom constant in a parameter section

Tags: variables, inno-setup

For example, I would like to create a variable to store some directory in the `[Files]` section, like this: `mydir=CustomDir;` so I can reference it later when I'm importing my files

```
Source: "{mydir}\MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}";
Source: "{mydir}\MyProg.chm"; DestDir: "{app}";
```

I want to do this because later on I can easily change the directory of my importing files, and for other customizations in other parts.

Is there something in Inno that allow me to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the [Inno Setup Preprocessor](http://ispp.sourceforge.net/).

That is good for compile-time constants. If you wanted to set a variable at install-time, you could use Inno Setup's Pascal scripting.